# Python Decorator Scoping Issues

Tags: python, class, static, decorator

I have a static class that has a method hello. I want to run the decorator method bar before hello. However, using the following code I always get a "name 'bar' is not defined" error. Does anyone know what's going on? Thanks!

```
class foo():
    @staticmethod
    @bar
    def hello():
        print "hello"

    def bar(fn):
        def wrapped():
            print "bar"
            return fn()
        return wrapped

foo.hello()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's not defined yet. Besides, that decorator shouldn't be a method at all.

```
def bar(fn):
    # ...

class foo(object):
    @staticmethod
    @bar
    def hello():
        # ...

# ...
```

Also, don't use static methods, unless you really know what you're doing. Make it a free function instead.

Comment: Why "don't use static methods"?

Comment: @agf: Because they're basically useless. Class methods are useful in certain situations, but I can't think of a use case for a static method. This isn't Java.

Comment: Just to keep things organized, if you have more than one class in a module.

Answer (score 2):

You can just change your code to:

```
def bar(fn):
    def wrapped():
        print "bar"
        return fn()
    return wrapped
class foo():
    @staticmethod
    @bar
    def hello():
        print "hello"
foo.hello()
```

This happens because you have to define a function before you call it. This is a problem because this:

```
@bar
def hello():
    print "hello"
```

is equivalent to:

```
def hello():
    print "hello"
hello = bar(hello)
```

So you were trying to call the function before you defined it.